# How to resolve "not counted" in perf?

Tags: linux, performance, x86, perf

perf stat -d ./sample.out
Output is:

```
Performance counter stats for './sample.out':

          0.586266 task-clock (msec)         #    0.007 CPUs utilized          
                 2 context-switches          #    0.003 M/sec                  
                 1 cpu-migrations            #    0.002 M/sec                  
               116 page-faults               #    0.198 M/sec                  
          7,35,790 cycles                    #    1.255 GHz                     [81.06%]
     <not counted> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
     <not counted> instructions            
     <not counted> branches                
     <not counted> branch-misses           
   <not supported> L1-dcache-loads:HG      
     <not counted> L1-dcache-load-misses:HG
     <not counted> LLC-loads:HG            
   <not supported> LLC-load-misses:HG      

       0.088013919 seconds time elapsed
```

I read why  will show up from . But I am getting  for even basic counters like instructions, branches etc. Can anyone suggest how to make it work?

Interesting thing is:

> sudo perf stat sleep 3

gives output:

```
Performance counter stats for 'sleep 3':

          0.598484 task-clock (msec)         #    0.000 CPUs utilized          
                 2 context-switches          #    0.003 M/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               181 page-faults               #    0.302 M/sec                  
     <not counted> cycles                  
     <not counted> stalled-cycles-frontend 
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
     <not counted> instructions            
     <not counted> branches                
     <not counted> branch-misses
```

> sudo perf stat -C 1 sleep 3

```
 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 1':

       3002.640578 task-clock (msec)         #    1.001 CPUs utilized           [100.00%]
               425 context-switches          #    0.142 K/sec                   [100.00%]
                 9 cpu-migrations            #    0.003 K/sec                   [100.00%]
                 5 page-faults               #    0.002 K/sec                  
       7,82,97,019 cycles                    #    0.026 GHz                     [33.32%]
       9,38,21,585 stalled-cycles-frontend   #  119.83% frontend cycles idle    [33.32%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
       3,09,81,643 instructions              #    0.40  insns per cycle        
                                             #    3.03  stalled cycles per insn [33.32%]
         70,15,390 branches                  #    2.336 M/sec                   [33.32%]
          6,38,644 branch-misses             #    9.10% of all branches         [33.32%]

       3.001075650 seconds time elapsed
```

Why is this unexpected working.??

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

The typical problem of `perf stat -d` for very short programs is not the statistical sampling, but **multiplexing** (percent in square brackets says `[33%]` - this counter was counted only for around 33% of running time).

You ask your PMU to monitor too many events at once, and perf is unable to map all required counters on real hardware (PMU - performance monitoring unit of the CPU) in same time. Typical PMU may have something like 4 or 7 or 8 independent counters, but the number may be divided by two if you have some SMT technology enabled (for example, HT - HyperThreading).

When you ask perf to count so many counters (you have 6 supported HW events in your perf stat output), it will divide all them into smaller groups. Groups will be changed by kernel at some points in time, when perf_events got chance to change them, for example on task-clock tick (~3 ms).

*You can split your run into several* with smaller sets of events - any number of SW events and 2-4 HW events per run:

```
perf stat -e task-clock,page-faults,cycles,stalled-cycles-frontend 
perf stat -e task-clock,page-faults,cycles,instructions            
perf stat -e task-clock,page-faults,branches,branch-misses           
perf stat -e task-clock,page-faults,L1-dcache-load-misses:HG,LLC-loads:HG
```

Answer (score -1):

`sudo perf stat -C 1 sleep 3` profiles *everything* that happens on CPU 1, all processes and kernel code.  That's why `sudo` is required.  That's also why the task-clock is ~3002 ms.

`perf stat sleep 3` (which doesn't need `sudo`) profiles only the `sleep(1)` process itself.  The task-clock measured it at ~0.6 ms of CPU time.

---

`sleep` hardly does anything itself; most of the instructions that run are in the dynamic linker.  As @osgx's answer points out, you're missing counts because `perf` doesn't have enough hardware counters on your machine, so it's multiplexing them.  The counters with no counts must have been recording while `sleep` was sleeping, not running.

For good results, put your microbenchmark in a loop that runs at least a hundred milliseconds, preferably ~1 sec for good signal-to-noise ratio, depending on what counters you're counting.

Comment: `perf stat` is not statistical sampling (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=4.4 - "Builtin stat command: Give a **precise** performance counters summary overview about any workload, CPU or specific PID"), it should be plain counting mode of hw pmu, capable of seeing every event. `sleep 1` and `echo 1` both do a lot of syscalls (check `strace sleep 1` or `ltrace sleep 1`) and they all have hundreds of thousands cycles and instructions. Only perf record is statistical sampling. You can also add -vv flag after stat to check "sampling" field of perf_events syscall.

Comment: @osgx: I meant that the HW PMU itself does sample, by only triggering an interrupt every 50k instructions/cycles/branches or whatever, right?  It can't fire an interrupt every clock cycle.  Or can you get the exact counts out after, even for counters that never rolled over and triggered an interrupt?

Comment: @osgx:  Anyway, your answer is clearly the right one; thanks for correcting my error.  I didn't look closely enough at the `-C` output to notice it was multiplexing counters, and that completely explains the OP's observations.

Comment: HW PMU doesn't sample, it does counting. But most CPU's classic PMU has interrupt-on-overflow mode (x86 - PerfEvtSel0.PC=0, .INT=1), and you can write "-N"  (-100000) to its counter before starting counting. After counting 100k events it will overflow and generate interrupt; perf_events for `perf record -c N` will reset this counter to -N and same event to get sampling. (uncore PMU may have no overflow interrupt, and precise PMU or PMU with trace store in memory like PEBS or LBR may have real sampling mode)(PC=1, INT=1 will fire every _event_, event may be rare, asserted INT will disable fire)

Comment: And yes, there is almost always the accessible register for current value of counter, so for every pmu channel (independently counting module) we have two registers, one to select event and set flags, and other to count events. For example, in early x86: http://www.cse.msu.edu/~enbody/pc_perfmon/ "four Model Specific Registers (MSR's): the performance event select registers (PerfEvtSel0 and PerfEvtSel1)  ... the performance counter MSR's (PerfCtr0 and PerfCtr1) .. contain the event .. count for the selected events being counted. Writing to these counters can be only done at privilege level 0"

Comment: @osgx: Thanks!  I'd been meaning to learn more about how perf counters count these days, and what PEBS was.  I took out the wrong stuff in my answer, leaving only the hopefully-useful advice and the difference between the OP's `-C` and not `-C`.